# insert code error

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server-2008

```
insert into customer (Advance,status)
values(@Advance,@status)
where Name='" + txtcname.Text.Trim() + "'";
```

in the above insert statement in going to insert 2 values based in condition but i'm getting error in `where` condition...

> incorrect syntax near keyword where

this is the error

Answer (score 4):

Insert query do not needs Where clause. Just write

`insert into customer (Advance, status) values(@Advance, @status)`

Are you trying to insert or update? if you need to update an existing record then use update instead of insert like this:

```
update customer set Advance=@Advance, status=@status 
where Name='" + txtcname.Text.Trim() + "'";
```

**EDIT**

Aforementioned update query will serve the purpose but its recommended to use stored procedures/parameterized queries for SQL injection safety. You should following use approach:

```
Private void UpdateRecord(string advance,string status, string name)
{
//SqlConnection con
SqlCommand cmdUpdate = new SqlCommand("update customer set Advance = @Advance, status = @Status where Name=@Name", con);
            cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Advance", advance);
            cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", status);            
            cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
            cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
```

Pass your data as following:

```
UpdateRecord(@Advance,@Status,txtcname.Text.Trim());
```

Comment: While your answer is probably correct, it should also change the `where` clause to work with parameters, and explain why.

Comment: Where clause cannot be used with insert, see the syntax examples here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386894/sql-server-insert-example , https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Comment: Unless you do an `insert into tableA select * from tableB` **where**.

Comment: 1. `Where` clause can be used with `insert`, if it's an `insert...select`. 2. I agree that the OP is probably looking for an `update` statement, and not an `insert` statement. 3. The `where` clause in **your** `update` statement is not parameterized, making the statement vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. Fix that, and you'll get my upvote as well.

Comment: @ZoharPeled,as per documentation insert..select still does not make the where part of insert instead its part of select. having a work around to combine two queries does not mean its part of insert.

Comment: @Munawar while true, this nitpicking is not related to my original (and more important) comment. The statement you posted is vulnerable, you should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use 'where' in an insert-statement. 
To achieve the same result, you can insert all entries and delete the wrong.

You can use a select-statement after an insert, where you select entries from a table into another. This could be a solution for you, too.

```
Insert into customer (advance, status) values (...)
select advance, status
from anotherCustomerTable
where ...
```

P.S. try to prepare the where-part, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can not add where clause with values. You can achieve this with following way
if you really want to insert new rows else you can follow the @Munawar solution

```
insert into customer (Advance, status)

SELECT @Advance,@status
FROM  customer where Name='" + txtcname.Text.Trim() + "'"
```